# How can a 900 pound item be sold?

Tags: economy

There is a treasure chest. It is very heavy. It has valuables inside it. The owner wants to sell it to someone else. The item is not mobile and cannot be given to the other person physically. It is too heavy for either of them to lift. But the owner wants to sell the item to the buyer.

How can this treasure box change ownership without being physically moved?

Comment: Can the buyer loot the chest after purchase and take the items inside it?

Comment: @Alexander no. It is known that there are valuables in it, but no one can access them.

Comment: There is nowhere to input a key, code, or biometric

Comment: Where is this chest? Public location or some secret one?

Comment: @Alexander Public location

Comment: How can this <piece of land> change ownership without being physically moved? How can this <house> change ownership without being physically moved? How can somebody buy next year's wheat crop which does not even exist yet? (The minus one is for the incongruous idea of a *chest* which is not movable. For information, in the year 37 CE, emperor Caligula ordered the transportation of a 331 tonne (730,000 pounds) Egyptian obelisk from Alexandria to Rome; it has been standing ever since in what is now St. Peter's Square. A 400 kilogram is trivially easy to carry away.)

Comment: How does real estate get sold without moving it? Buy the patch of land the chest is standing on and build a house around it.

Comment: @AlexP So it can be sold and change ownership?

Comment: Yes, it can be sold and change ownership. Coins were invented about 2,600 years ago, and we know for sure that stuff was bought and sold long before the invention of coins. The oldest contract for the sale of real estate which we have found is about 4,000 years old -- a Sumerian man named [Sini-Ishtar bought some land](https://sourcebooks.fordham.edu/ancient/mesopotamia-contracts.asp) and a house for four and a half shekels of silver; the sale was recorded in writing and the names of 14 witnesses are mentioned.

Comment: The seller puts "You Haul" on the advert and lets the buyer deal with that problem.

Comment: "It is known that there are valuables in it, but no one can access them." Why buy it, then? A box full of gold that I can never access isn't useful. (I guess an indestructible 900-pound box might itself be valuable if you're shopping for, say, a portcullis, but it would be rather inconvenient if it can't be moved.)

Comment: VTC:NDS. Is there even a worldbuilding problem here? Are you asking about changes to your culture's laws (need details about the culture's legal system) or are you asking about the philosophy of ownership (I don't think you can provide enough details about that one) or are you asking if the buyer's emotional state would permit them to buy something they can't move? Why can't the chest be emptied a bit at a time? Is it a single 900# block of gold? What rule of your world are you asking about? (Because if you're not asking about a rule of your world, the Q is entirely off-topic.)

Comment: Agree with JBH's vote: At the moment, seems too obvious for a question (stuff doesn't need to be mobile in order to change ownership/title), essentially a question about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rai_stones, but with some obscuring detail about replacing the stones with a "chest" (obscuring because everyone thinks of chests as portable, openable, lootable containers, almost by definition). Could become an interesting question with some work, at which point answers might also consider the crossover with real artworks vs modern NFTs of them, but for now, VTC.

Answer (score 3):

## Cart

[image]

One team of musclebodies lifts the heavy box onto the cart. The donkeys pull the cart where it needs to go. Then another team of musclebodies removes the chest from the cart.

Comment: This answer inadvertently (but happily) illustrates the remarkable difference in head size between a young donkey and a fully grown one!

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer**

From comments:

> Ownership means in this instance that it is legally recognized

This means moving the chest is irrelevant. You need these to be verifiable without the intervention of the seller:

- The law to recognize the seller had ownership of the object.
- The law to recognize the seller agreed to transfer that ownership to the buyer.

So the buyer can use these to demonstrate ownership.

I don't know how ownership was first acquired, but there must be legislation about it.

And for the transfer, have a document signed. The buyer wants to keep a copy to demonstrate it happened.

And of course, we can presume the law wants to prevent the seller to sell the chest multiple times. Thus, there must be a government organization that holds a copy. That can check their archives to trace the ownership. So they can verify who is the owner.

The document must entail the identity of the transferred object, the identities of both parties, in a way that the law can recognize it is not a forgery, and the intent to transfer ownership. And any other details the law may require.

---

**Old answer**

- 900 pound item is movable. If they can't move it, perhaps they can use the help of a couple more people, or they can use a fork lift, or have horses pull it, or whatever is appropiate for the setting.
- Build around it. Perhaps the cannot access the chest, but can create a structure around the chest that only them can access, by the appropriate security for the setting.
- If you can't build around it, perhaps you can hire guards for it.
- Make a public declaration and have it in public record. So every known and agrees on who owns the chest. See also [Rai Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rai_stones).
- Similarly a letter, signed in duplicate, by hand, would hold in most courts. Or whatever form of contract is appropriate for your setting.

Comment: So it can be sold and change ownership?

Comment: @Topac72 Do you have a particular definition of ownership you want the answer to abide by? Edit: notice I know little of your setting (e.g. fantasy, sci-fi...? law, technology…?)

Comment: Ownership means in this instance that it is legally recognized

Comment: @Topac72 ...well, does the local legal system recognize the seller's ownership of the chest and their right to transfer that ownership to the buyer? This seems like a question only you can answer...though it would be a bit of an odd quirk of the legal system for the answer to be "no" simply because it's too heavy for one person to lift unassisted.

Answer (score 0):

Sale contract

Resisting the temptation for a frame challenge here:
A simple contract of sale.
This is how big, heavy objects have been sold forever.

A merchant or businessman or anyone goes and inspects the bulk bag/machine/ore stock/house/treasure chest, agrees a price with the seller, and writes down a contract outlining:

1. Price
2. Payment method
3. Delivery time, if any
4. Right of access, if the object is immobile.
5. Any remaining stake or rights of the seller (often spelled out as none).
6. Liability if the item is damaged or stolen before contract completion.

The buyer and seller then provide a socially acceptable proof that they agreed. It's a signature at the moment, but in the past it was a wax seal or an exchange of an item by convention (e.g. in Ruth 4 in the Bible, they used an exchange of sandals).

The seller issues the buyer with a receipt once paid.

This is actually a better than normal case for this for a treasure chest, where a contract is a waste of time and the treasure is bound to be stolen.

In this case, for some reason, 400 kg is too heavy for anyone to move (400 kg isn't normally too hard for a group of people; AlexP's example of the Romans importing monuments is a good one).
Also, for some reason the box is unlootable right now.

Great, it's a perfect case for a contract of sale. You can find historical examples from whatever place and time period you like on the internet to get the style right.

If the setting is modern, you can find millions of stock examples to draw one up, even without a lawyer. And any lawyer can write one.

Answer (score 0):

**Move the contents over several trips.**

It seems like an attractive prospect to move a refrigerator full of beer to the locale where you intend to drink the beer.  But beer is heavy.  The full refrigerator is unwieldy.  The beer will shift all around in there as you try to schlep the fridge.  It will get shook up.  It is a plan that sounds good only after a fair amount of the beer has already been consumed.

So too your fridge.   I mean chest.  It is full of valuable and heavy beer.  You will open the chest and move as many items as you can comfortably tote at once.  I here note that trenchcoats have several pockets that can accomodate at least one bottle each.

Once you have made the trips you will get the empty chest itself.  You will bring a skateboard you found in your brother's room to put the chest on, and you will stand in the chest with one leg and push with the other, skateboarding your chest to its new home.

There you will load it back with remaining valuable items.